# nest.js upsertMany causes high memory

Tags: javascript, nestjs

There is a scheduled task, which is executed every 5 minutes when using upsertMany to insert a large amount of data. I found that the memory will increase every time the task is executed, and the GC cannot reclaim the memory. How can I solve this problem?

use nestjs , @mikro-orm/nestjs

```
this.emBi.upsertMany(SingleOrderSales, saveArry)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager) it seems you need to manually perform the flush command after you finish working with entity manager (also do not forget to await it). in your case:

```
await this.emBi.flush();
```